# Magento 2.3 - How to move menu ( catalog.topnav ) after logo ( header.panel )?

Tags: magento2.3.4, menu, logo

I have created a custom which is inherited from the blank theme, I want to move my menu ( catalog.topnav ) after the logo ( header.panel ) ?

Comment: You can try like: `<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>` because existing logo is referenced in  `header-wrapper` wrapper

Comment: Mobile view collapsed https://snipboard.io/UKZG32.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to move menu catalog topnav after logo,
> Go to your theme default.xml

```
  <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper"  after="logo"/>
```

> This will move menu catalog topnav after logo.
> You have to work on with custom css for mobile view.

Comment: Yes i did, but i have new issue, after move menu to header panel in mobile view menu look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPsJu.png

Comment: Post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328503/custom-theme-after-move-catalog-topnav-to-header-panel-mobile-view-category-disp

Comment: I have created custom theme using blank theme, anything i need to setup?

Comment: If my practice wrong, pls help me.